# Как проверить, является ли упомянутый участник ботом(discord.py)?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Я попробовал использовать такой код:

```
@bot.command()
async def check(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send("Упомините пользователя")
    else:
        if member is bot:
            await ctx.send("Это Бот")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Это не бот")
```

но у меня постоянно отправляло "Это не бот" когда я проверял какого-либо пользователя.

Comment: Попробуйте `if member.bot:`

Comment: @ГеннадийП сработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Для этого делается данная проверка:

```
if member.bot == True:
    print("Это бот")
```